# Gradle - Corda flow tests fail when run from the command line

Tags: gradle, junit, kotlin, corda, quasar

In my project I have a module that contains Corda flow tests written in Kotlin, and using JUnit. Most of the tests pass, except for the flow tests

My assumption is that this is because Corda flow tests require `-ea -javaagent:lib/quasar.jar` in the command line...

In my `gradle.build` file I've added

```
test {
    jvmArgs "-ea -javaagent:lib/quasar.jar"
}
```

And then from the command line I'm running `./gradlew test` but I get these errors from the flow tests:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException

*Further Investigations*

Running `./gradlew test --info` suggests that the jvm arguments are being ignored altogether:

> com.acme.FlowTests > Issuance flow should be signed by the initiator FAILED
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing the '-javaagent' JVM argument. Make sure you run the tests with the Quasar java agent attached to your JVM. See https://docs.corda.net/troubleshooting.html - 'Fiber classes not instrumented' for more details.
>
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property network has not been initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was specifying `jvmArgs` in the wrong module. Adding the following line to `gradle.build` of the module that contains the tests fixed the issue:

```
test.jvmArgs = ["-ea", "-javaagent:../lib/quasar.jar"]
```